# Two-dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that returns pointer to two-dimensional array of pointers. I have this array: `Organism* worldTab[20][20];` and my friend advised to write the function I want in this way:

```
    Organism** getWorldTab() {
    return worldTab[20];
}
```

Is it correct? When I want to do this (`temp` is `Organism*** temp;`):

```
    *temp = world.getWorldTab();
```

Visual Studio throws an exception

```
    Exception thrown: write access violation.

    this->temp was 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

and I am pretty sure `getWorldTab()`functions is a problem.

worldTab definition: `Organism* worldTab[20][20];`

Comment: `worldTab[20]` is out of bounds.

Comment: You need to give more context. Where is `worldTab` defined?

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and Edit your question

Comment: `Organism***` -- three stars is a sure sign of trouble.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things, for example the storage class of `worldTab`. But it's a bad idea in any case. Use `std::vector` instead of this horrible low-level pointer management.

Comment: @PeteBecker it's two though.

Comment: @GillBates - "temp is `Organism*** temp;`", three stars.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can you clean my glasses while you're at it? I should learn to read.

Comment: I added the worldTab definition to my question

Comment: Why `return world[20]` ?

Comment: @Sniper I was told that I should write one of the two array's dimensions while returning it

Comment: The error message says the problem is `*temp`, not `getWorldTab`.

Comment: @melpomene in that case I honestly have no idea what is wrong with *temp

Comment: Neither do we if you don't post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

An array is not a pointer, although it can be converted into a pointer to its first element in some situations, and a pointer to an array is completely unlike a pointer to a pointer.

A pointer to your array has the type `Organism* (*)[20][20]`.

A pointer to the first element of the array is probably what your friend had in mind, but that has the type `Organism* (*)[20]`, not `Organism**` or `Organism***`, and can't be converted to either.

(And, as a bonus, `worldTab[20]` is out of bounds because it would be the twenty-first array of the twenty that exist. And you never initialised `temp` before assigning to `*temp`, which is the source of the access violation.)

While you could write

```
Organism* (*getWorldTab())[20] {
    return &worldTab[0];
}

Organism* (*temp)[20] = getWorldTab();
```

or simply

```
Organism* (*temp)[20] = worldTab;
```

I think you should learn to use `std::vector` and `std::array` – they relieve a lot of pain.
(Plus, it's 2017. While it can be interesting, there's no need to program like it's 1969.)